# How to deal with a indicator function in a likelihood?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

**Question**: A panel study followed 25 married couples over five years. One item of interest is the relationship between divorce rates and the various characteristics of the couples. For example, the researchers would like to model the probability of divorce as a function of age differential, recorded as the man’s age minus the woman’s age. The data can be found in the file divorce.dat. We will model these data with probit regression, in which a binary variable Yi is described in terms of an explanatory variable xi via the following latent variable model:
$$Z_i=\beta x_i+\varepsilon_i,\\ Y_i=\delta_{(c,\infty)}(Z_i),$$
where $\beta, c$ are unknown coefficients, and $\epsilon_i,\cdots,\epsilon_n \sim \text{i.i.d.} N(0,1)$, and $\delta_{(c,\infty)}(z)=1$ if $z\in (c,\infty)$ and zero otherwise.

**Here's the problem**: Assuming $c ∼ N(0, \tau_c^2)$, show that $p(c|\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}, β)$ is a constrained normal density, i.e. proportional to a normal density but constrained to lie in an interval. Similarly, show that $p(z_i|\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}_{−i},β,c)$ is proportional to a normal density but constrained to be either above c or below c, depending on $y_i$. (Note that $\mathbf{z}_{-i}$ means all other $z$'s except for $i$th value.)
I want to know how to deal with $\delta$.

**My idea**: First of all, it is obvious that $p(c|\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}, β)\propto p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{z},c)p(c)$. Since each $Z_i$ is independent due to $\epsilon_i$, $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{z},c)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|z_i,c)$. I'm stuck in here. Also, for $p(z_i|\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}_{−i},β,c)$, I could never get the hang of it. I think that the two are something like a normal distribution.

Comment: You're describing an (almost) ordinary probit model $P(Y_i=1|x_i) = P(Z_i > c|x_i) = P(\epsilon_i > c - \beta x_{i}) = \Phi(\alpha + \beta x_i)$ where $\alpha = -c$ and $\Phi$ is the [normal CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/425564), see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/526287) or [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/57245/14365) for more details.